# (Getting Error message) Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in

Tags: php

I installed on my shared hosting about 6 months ago its been working great until now.

im getting this error message

```
Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in /home/hit/public_html/twando/inc/include_top.php on line 32
```

The error is pointing to this line of code

```
$filename = array_pop(explode("/",$url_check));
```

Here is the full file include_top.php

```
/*
Config
*/

ob_start();
include('config.php');
ob_end_clean();

/*
Includes
*/

include('class/class.mysql.php');
include('class/class.mainfuncs.php');
include('class/twitteroauth.php');
include('content/' . TWANDO_LANG . '/lang.php');

/*
URL of intall. You can override this if you wish
with a static define in config.php
*/

if (!defined(BASE_LINK_URL)) {
 if ($_SERVER['HTTPS']) {$url_check = 'https://';} else {$url_check = 'http://';}
 $url_check .= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
 $filename = array_pop(explode("/",$url_check));  <<----Line 32 error
 $url_check = str_replace($filename,"",$url_check);
 define('BASE_LINK_URL',$url_check);
}

/*
Internal defines - you shouldn't need to change these
*/

define('TWANDO_VERSION','0.6');
define('TWITTER_API_LIMIT',15);
define('TWITTER_API_LIST_FW',5000);
define('TWITTER_API_USER_LOOKUP',100);
define('TABLE_ROWS_PER_PAGE',10);
define('TWITTER_TWEET_SEARCH_PP',100);
define('TWITTER_USER_SEARCH_PP',20);

/*
Start
*/

$db = new mySqlCon();
session_start();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to do this in two steps: `$temp = explode("/",$url_check); $filename = array_pop($temp);`

Comment: But why not use [parse_url()](http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)?

Comment: @MarkBaker nevermind, just me being stupid. Sorry :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array_pop()` needs to be passed a variable, because only variables can be [passed by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) in php. You pass `explode("/",$url_check)` to `array_pop()`, which isn't a variable. You can fix the error like this:

```
$array = explode("/", $url_check);
$filename = array_pop($array);
```

Comment: thanks guys i tried your solution Jonan and it worked thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding extra brackets:

```
$filename = array_pop((explode("/", "http://example.com/foo/bar"))
```

See: [Occasionally significant parentheses](http://phpsadness.com/sad/51)